# Arduino sends \376(broken data?) on serial port

Tags: xcode, serial-port, arduino, openframeworks

I'm making serial program between arduino and openframeworks. But arduino sent strange data to openframeworks program. I couldn't fix it, please help.

(arduino code)

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.write('a');
  delay(100);
}
```

(opneframeworks code on Mac)

```
#include "testApp.h"

ofSerial mySerial;

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup(){
    mySerial.setup(0, 9600);

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){

    unsigned char myByte = 0;
    myByte = mySerial.readByte();

    if(myByte == OF_SERIAL_NO_DATA){
        cout << "no data was read";
    }else if(myByte == OF_SERIAL_ERROR){
        cout << "an error occurred";
    }else{
        cout << "myByte is " << myByte << "\n";
    }

}
```

(console on Xcode)

```
...
myByte is \376
myByte is \376
myByte is a
myByte is \376
myByte is \376
myByte is \376
myByte is \376
...
```

It seems OpenFrameworks on Mac got "\376" when Arduino didn't send any data.
My environment is,

- Mac OS Lion
- Xcode v4.3.3 SDK10.6
- OpenFrameworks v0.7.4 for Mac
- Arduino IDE v1.0.4
- Arduino uno(atmega328p)
- Arduino and my PC are connected with USB cable

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that this is an issue of your Serial Buffer being incomplete when you are trying to read it - 9 times out of 10 when I've received odd data in Processing or openFrameworks, that's been the issue.

Try to change your update() method to :

```
void testApp::update(){

    unsigned char myByte = 0;
    if(myByte.available > 8 {
      myByte = mySerial.readByte();
    }

    if(myByte == OF_SERIAL_NO_DATA){
        cout << "no data was read";
    }else if(myByte == OF_SERIAL_ERROR){
        cout << "an error occurred";
    }else{
        cout << "myByte is " << myByte << "\n";
    }

}
```

As per the [oF Serial Class Documentation](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/serial/ofSerial.html#show_available)